# how to use ValidateScopes in autofac?

Tags: autofac

if i use default ioc in asp.net core,i can use this option :

```cs
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) => {
        options.ValidateScopes = true;
    })
```

but how to use this config in autofac? I don't see any relevant documentation on the github homepage

> When ValidateScopes is set to true, the default service provider performs checks to verify that:
> Scoped services aren't directly or indirectly resolved from the root service provider.
> Scoped services aren't directly or indirectly injected into singletons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ValidateScopes - as with UseDefaultServiceProvider - are both not Autofac. There is no equivalent in Autofac. [There is documentation about caprice dependencies](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html) but nothing to prevent you from doing it.